# cant add IOS platform to cordova project

Tags: cordova

iam developing a mobile app using `Phonegap` for Android and IOS platform on Command line.

I created a project on my desktop and i added android platform to the project but when i try to add IOS platform using the command-

```
cordova platform add ios
```

Iam gettting error shown in the image

[image: Error ehile adding ios platform to cordova project]

I am not able to get what the problem is.   Please help !!!

Project name is `CorwiV1`.

Answer (score 1):

First You need MAC os and Developer Tools like Xcode for ios for developing and download phonegap's latest version and for create Phonegap Project in ios follow this link [Create Phonegap Project in ios](http://grdevore.screenstepslive.com/s/ispring-phonegap/m/8836/l/91464-lesson-4-creating-the-xcode-project-using-phonegap) 
. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Are you using Phonegap or Cordova?

I would recommend you to read the [Cordova Documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) of how to get started with this. After you downloaded Cordova you have to install [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/). <- Sorry, wrong way, FIRST install NodeJS and after that you install cordova over the terminal.

If you did this all, you have to create a Project like this:

- open terminal
- cd ~/desktop
- cordova create test com.example.test
- cd test
- cordova platform add ios/android etc.
- cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.plugin
- cordova build

When you've finished this, you should see 2 folder called "android" and "ios" in your test mainfolder.

**Keep in mind that you can not develop/publish iOS apps on a Windows Computer!**

Maybe you look into the [Getting started with iOS Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide)

Comment: ya i did all the initial step and i have created app for android but now when i try to add ios platform i was shown that error.    If i have to create app for IOS in my pc with windows 7 os using phonegap what procedure i have to adopt. i tried to download ios sdk but im not able to download.

Comment: Did you read my answer? Youre not able to install the SDK on a Windows PC!

You can not develop an ios application in XCode on a Windows Computer. Did you install node.js, and installed cordova over the console?